# How to determine whether this integral converges $ \int_x^{t-x}e^{-2\alpha (t-r)}\bigg(\frac{1}{t-r}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}}dr $？

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Consider the following integral that $t\to \infty$, $x\to \infty$ and $x/t\to 0$,
$$
\int_x^{t-x}e^{-2\alpha (t-r)}\bigg(\frac{1}{t-r}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}}dr
$$
where $\alpha>0$.

I would like to know if the above integral converges. If not, what is the order $O(\cdot)$?

---

It seems that as $t\to \infty$ we have $e^{-2\alpha (t-r)}\to 0$ and $\bigg(\frac{1}{t-r}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}}\to 0$. Can we say it converges to 0?

Comment: It will depend on $\alpha$. Change variable $u=t-r$

Comment: @Andrei I think OP is implicitly assuming positive $\alpha$

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes, $\alpha>0$